# Implementing FadeOut/FadeIn in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My problem is that only fadeOut works but not fadeIn. I don't use CSS or jQuery for it. And how can I make my code more effective.

The code:

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"id="circle1"onclick="myFunction()"></div>
<div class="circle"id="circle2" style="visibility:visible" ></div
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("circle2");
  if (element.style.visibility === "visible") {
    var op = 1;
    var timer = setInterval(frame, 100)

    function frame() {
      if (op <= 0.1) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        element.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }
      element.style.opacity = op;
      op -= op * 0.1;
    }
  } else {
    var op = 0;
    var timer = setInterval(frame, 10)

    function frame() {
      if (op >= 0.95) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        element.style.visibility = "visible";
      }
      element.style.opacity = op;
      op += op * 0.1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons this is not working.

1. 0 * anything is still 0 so var op=0; and op += op * 0.1 will always be zero.
2. It is set to hidden not visible while transitioning to fully visible.

I played around with it to make it work but I refactored you code to fit my style while I did it. This is what I came up with.

```js
function myFunction() {

    var element = document.getElementById( "circle2" );
    var op;
    var timer;

    if ( element.style.visibility === "visible" ) {
        op = 1;
        timer = setInterval( fadeOut, 100 )
    } else {
        op = 0.1;
        timer = setInterval( fadeIn, 100 )
    }

    function fadeOut() {
        if ( op <= 0.1 ) {
            clearInterval( timer );
            element.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }

    function fadeIn() {
        element.style.visibility = "visible";
        if ( op >= 0.95 ) {
            clearInterval( timer );
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        op += op * 0.1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"id="circle1"onclick="myFunction()">hello</div>
<div class="circle"id="circle2" style="visibility:visible" >Test</div>
```

Comment: why ist the **element.style.visibility = "visible";** outside of the if statement? It works but why.

Comment: Because of issue number 2. We need the element to have the visible attribute so when we change the opacity we will see the change. If it is in the if statement the opacity will change been we won't see anything because the element when still be hidden.